# Stack Overflow jobs not updating to my new status

Tags: support, bug, stack-overflow-jobs

I think there is an issue in your Jobs matches code.  I have accepted a job and am no longer in the market.  I have updated my preferences on SO.  But I still get the emails, and I also still have the larger than regular jobs section when browsing the site.  It may just by my account, but I don't recall doing anything very special with my account.  Also, the links, including unsubscribe, from the job emails all link to 404 pages.

Last job email received 11/20/2020

Subject: New jobs that match your saved search on Stack Overflow

Broken links:
Unsubscribe from this email -- 404 -- https://stackoverflow.com/users/email/job-alerts/unsubscribe-all?id=2f02cabab2ac4ab79e...

Edit email settings  -- 404 -- https://stackoverflow.com/users/email/settings/?id=2f02cabab2a...

Comment: can you provide a bit more information to assist with troubleshooting this. In particular, could you provide the subject line of some of the emails you are still getting? Could you clarify what you mean by "larger than regular jobs section"? And could you provide some examples of the URLs that aren't working (just the hostname and the page, not the parameters)?

Comment: for some reason, it appears you had two users defined in our Careers system .. perhaps you at one time had multiple Stack Overflow users and had them merged together?  In any case, the second account appears to now have been cleaned up.  If you continue to receive the emails, please let us know.